# Dynamic item template slots within v-data-table with custom components & helpers

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, datatable, vuetify.js, v-data-table

Say I have a custom component that uses Vuetify's [`v-data-table`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) within.

Within this component, there's multiple other custom components such as loaders and specific column-based components for displaying data in a certain way.

I found myself using the same code for filtering, retrieving data, loaders etc. across the project - so not very DRY.

The things that vary are:

1. API request url to retrieve data from (which I can pass to this generic component)
2. headers for `v-data-table` (which I pass to this generic component)
3. specific item slot templates!
   (One file using this same code would need a column modification like the below, requiring different components sometimes too):

   ```javascript
     <template v-slot:[`item.FullName`]="{ item }">
       <router-link class="black--text text-decoration-none" :to="'/users/' + item.Id">
        <Avatar :string="item.FullName" />
       </router-link>
     </template>
   ```

   Where another would have for example:

   ```javascript
     <template v-slot:[`item.serial`]="{ item }">
       <copy-label :text="item.serial" />
     </template>
   ```

   There are many more unique "column templates" that I use obviously, this is just an example.
4. modifying items passed to `v-data-table` in a computed property (to add "actions" or run cleanups and/or modify content before displaying it - not related to actual HTML output, but value itself)

   ```javascript
     computed: {
       items () {
         if (!this.data || !this.data.Values) {
           return []
         }

        return this.data.Values.map((item) => {
          return {
            device: this.$getItemName(item),
            serial: item.SerialNumber,
            hwVersion: this.$getItemHwVersion(item),
            swVersion: this.$getItemSwVersion(item),
            actions: [
             { to: '/devices/' + item.Id, text: this.$t('common.open') },
             { to: '/devices/' + item.Id + '/replace', text: this.$t('common.replace') }
      ],
            ...item
         }
      })
   }
   ```
5. there are some unique methods that I can use on certain template slot item modifications, such as dateMoreThan24HoursAgo() below:

   ```javascript
     <template v-slot:[`item.LastLogin`]="{ item }">
        <span v-if="dateMoreThan24HoursAgo(item.LastLogin)">{{ item.LastLogin | formatDate }}</span>
        <span v-else>
          {{ item.LastLogin | formatDateAgo }}
        </span>
      </template>
   ```

   I can always make this global or provide them as a prop so this point should not be a big issue.

**So my questions are:**

1. What is the best way to use one component with `v-data-table` within but dynamically pass template slots and also allow item modification prior to passing the array to the v-data-table (as per point 3 and 4 above)
2. is there a better way to approach this since this seems too complex (should I just keep separate specific files)? It does not feel very DRY, that's why I'm not very fond of the current solution.

Basically I would be happy to have something like:

```javascript
data: () => {
    return {
      apiPath: 'devices',
      headers: [
        { text: 'Device', align: 'start', value: 'device', sortable: false, class: 'text-none' },
        { text: 'Serial Number', sortable: false, value: 'serial', class: 'text-none' },
        { text: 'Status', value: 'Status', class: 'text-none' },
        { text: 'Calibration', value: 'NextCalibrationDate', class: 'text-none' },
        { text: '', sortable: false, align: 'right', value: 'actions' }
      ],
      itemsModify: (items) => {
         return items.map((item) => {
           return {
             device: this.$getItemName(item),
             serial: item.SerialNumber,
             actions: [
              { to: '/devices/' + item.Id, text: this.$t('common.open') },
              { to: '/devices/' + item.Id + '/replace', text: this.$t('common.replace') }
              ],
             ...item
          }
        })
      },
      columnTemplatesPath: '/path/to/vue/file/with/templates' 
    }
  }
```

And then I'd just call my dynamic component like so:

```javascript
<GenericTable 
  :api-path="apiPath" 
  :headers="headers" 
  :items-modify="itemsModify" 
  :column-templates-path="columnTemplatesPath" 
/>
```

Relevant but not exactly a solution to my question:

- [Is it possible to use dynamic scoped slots to override column values inside <v-data-table>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61508925/is-it-possible-to-use-dynamic-scoped-slots-to-override-column-values-inside-v-d)
- [Dynamically building a table using vuetifyJS data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607082/dynamically-building-a-table-using-vuetifyjs-data-table)